# Converting a Regex from JS flavor to Golang flavor?

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to convert a certain regex from ECMAScript flavor to Golang flavor, here it is :

```
((r|)+)(( |\n)*)((|e)+)(( |\n)*)((p|)+)(( |\n)*)((|o)+)(( |\n)*)((|s)+)(( |\n)*)((t|)+)
```

Basically the point is to match messages like "r    p O s t".
I've tried to replace " " by "\s" but it's still not working. Any idea please?

Comment: Did the ECMAScript regex ever work properly? According to my calculations it would match `RR ee Pp OOOO s t` without issues.

Comment: The `\s` will work for you. You just did not use the raw string literal.

Comment: Use `[r]+` rather than `(r|)+` - the latter is inefficient. The same applies to any alternations for single character matches: `[ \n]*`, `[e]+`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is this working for you?

```
[r]\s*[e]\s*[p]\s*[o]\s*[s]\s*[t]
```

With case insensitive flag

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Rg410I/2)

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't match because your regex doesn't include an uppercase "O"

You can use this expression that includes it:

```
((r|)+)(( |\n)*)((|e)+)(( |\n)*)((p|)+)(( |\n)*)((|o|O)+)(( |\n)*)((|s)+)(( |\n)*)((t|)+)
```

In your Go code, make sure to use these quotes with it:

```
`((r|)+)(( |\n)*)((|e)+)(( |\n)*)((p|)+)(( |\n)*)((|o|O)+)(( |\n)*)((|s)+)(( |\n)*)((t|)+)`
```

Also [see here](https://regex101.com/r/sdEUdd/1)